# MongoDB index makes query worse

Tags: mongodb

when I put an index on a collection, the query takes longer.

```
> db.baz.drop();for(var n=0;n<100000;n++)db.baz.insert({i:n})
```

Without the index,

> db.baz.find({i: {$mod: [10,0]}}).explain()
>             "millis" : 107,

But with the index,

> db.baz.ensureIndex({i:1})
>   db.baz.find({i: {$mod: [10,0]}}).explain()
>           "millis" : 284,

How can this be?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: Yes, I wait until the prompt in the shell returns.

Comment: According to this 10gen presentation, `$mod` queries cannot make effective use of an index on the referenced field.  http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/indexing-with-mongodb

Comment: Plus the index adds overhead on inserts and querying as such it will be slower

Comment: The same question has also been reposted on [mongodb-users google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/4GLzfBrtcJI%5B1-25%5D) with some further discussion.

Comment: Paraphrasing the summary from Scott in the google group discussion: "In this case the `$mod` on the index is slowing things down since it has to return everything from the index and then do the `$mod` comparison with each doc. Since the index isn't selective at all, the index can't help much except with the `sort()`. Your data set is small and fits in memory so the index won't add much value.  The larger the data set and the more selective the index is (i.e. only a small portion of documents are returned), the better the performance increase of using the index will be.